# How do I open a port to the world in a security group in EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, port-forwarding

I tried to open a port to an AWS EC2 Windows instance, for example, port 12888. I created a new security rule in the security group, added the port 12888 in the port range but what shall I put in the source? I want the port be open for all clients.

Comment: Wich OS are you using? Did you open the port in the OS Firewall too ?

Comment: I'm using windows server in the instance and I'm checking port with a website http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Answer (score 1):

As you appear to have opened the port in the EC2 Security Group but still don't get an Open Port result from the page you link to I'm going to guess that you either

- Haven't opened the port on your OS firewall.
- Haven't got anything listening on the relevant port.

Or possible both. Either will cause that page to say the port is closed.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to add a new rule to a security group in the console, you should see `0.0.0.0/0` offered as the default value for the source IP address.

That address/mask matches all IP addresses and exposes your open port to the entire Internet, so that's the value to use, if that's what you're really wanting to do.

Comment: I did but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to try Iain's suggestions?
If so, and they did not work - we might need more information from you to assist further.

Are you using a VPC or in EC2 Classic?

When you say it is not working - how are you testing?

Are you using the right IP address to test?